# Running java command - could not open jar file

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to run a java command as shown here

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spatl/esri-shapefiles.html#GUID-D622DD73-BB4B-4105-B293-7AAB0BDE6E33

I have just changed the path to the jar files.

[image]

But then an error is shown

[image]

What is wrong with my script ?

**UPDATE**

After wrapping the classpath argument as suggested in the comment, I have a new message.

`Unable to initialize threads: cannot find class java/lang/Thread`

Comment: I *think* the issue is that in PowerShell the semicolon `;` is a command separator. This means you must quote the entire classpath argument using `"` to stop PS from splitting it and trying to execute the individual parts as commands. Also, I'm pretty amused that Acrobat Reader felt responsible for trying to open that file ...

Comment: This helped, but I have a new message.

Comment: *But then an error is shown* You're saying that after executing the java command somehow it gets translated to executing Adobe reader?

Comment: @user49126: please [edit] your question to contain the full command you execute now as text. And in the future, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also: that error message (as well as the fact that your usage summary contains `-nojit`) makes me think you're running an archaeologically ancient version of Java. What does `java -version` print?